# Efficient table-like type for basic scenarios, no sorting/persistence/searching

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, datatable

I'm looking for an efficient in-memory type that mimics a table of mixed-type data (rows/columns).  By efficient I mean fast operations for the below scenarios.  Memory is a secondary concern.

Primary scenarios are:

- add rows of data
- read whole columns
- iterate over rows

Out of scope:

- sorting/ordering
- searching
- persistence to database
- random access of cells (i.e. table(row=3,col=4) )

I'm assuming I can do better than the ADO types (DataTable, etc.) because they solve for a broader set of scenarios?  I could be wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with `DataTable`? And `DataSet`, and `DataReader`? What do you mean, 'better'?

Comment: _"I'm assuming I can do better than DataTable"_ What  leads to the assumption?

Comment: You don't specify what you mean by efficient (memory consumption, processing speed, ???) but it is pretty easy to do your three primary scenarios just using a `IEnumerable<T>` and LINQ statements to iterate/select.

Comment: Processing first, memory second.  The point is that there's overhead for both if you are solving for ordering/searching/etc.  Yes, ultimately I could build a wrapper around List<IEnumerable<T>>.  Was wondering if there was something already out there that was already unit tested

Comment: Some examples of the API you want to use would be helpful, because with the level of detail you have given, LINQ seems to be the appropriate API to me.

Comment: @Tim - intuition, but I could be wrong.  I'm happy for someone to tell me that they had a similar need and found DataTable efficient (speed of adding/retrieiving rows, speed of accessing whole columns)

Comment: @Grant - Updated post, looking for speed related to primary scenarios.  I'm not sure anything is wrong with the Data... classes, but they seem to solve for a broad set of scenarios so intuition tells me that I can do better with a more narrow set of scenarios.

Comment: Also don't forget `TypedTableBase<DataRowT>` that will be used if you add a database as DataSource to your project and `DataView` for easy filtering and sorting.

Comment: @SFun28: All that you have mentioned are core competencies of a `DataTable`(+`DataSet`+`DataAdapter`), so i doubt that you will find something better.

Comment: I did get DataTable to work, but I believe this is a case of trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.  Yes, you could jam it in.  DataTable is a beast.  Interacting with it (for my scenarios) always involves lots of casting.  Data in columns are accessed by iterating through rows; there is no O(1) fetching construct.  DataTable is the very definition of complexity - it plays multiple roles along multiple dimensions and as such some roles suffer.  The simplest way to think of a table is to imagine a spreadsheet like Excel.  In Excel, there's no hard thinking about how to copy a column.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable has a lot of features and has bulk.  Like AcceptChanges.

To handle the mixed data types created an abstract class

```
public abstract class Field : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

It includes

```
public abstract String DispValue { get; }
```

Then for the various data types

```
class FieldBooleanSV : Field

class FieldStringSV : Field

class FieldInt32SV : Field

public class FieldInt16SV : DocField
{
    Int16 fieldValue;
    Int16 FieldValue { get { return fieldValue; }
        set
        {
                if (value != fieldValue)
                {
                    fieldValue = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("DispValue");
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("FieldValue");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public override String DispValue 
    { 
        get 
        {  return fieldValue.ToString()); }
    }
}
```

SV is single value and there is a MV

So a FieldRow is a class with property

```
List<Field> Fields ....
```

And total collection is (rows and columns) is

```
ObservableCollection<FieldRow>
```

It is fragile as you need to sure that each FieldRow has the same collection of Fields.

It is a lot of work but I needed control of Field.
If you are going down this path then go GridView over DataGrid (for the same reasons - power but overhead).

The problem with

```
List<IEnumerable<T>>
```

Is that T is a variable but it is singular.  All columns are the same T.

Comment: Blam, I appreciate the post but honestly I can't follow what you are saying.

Comment: Do you want me to include more detail or just delete it?

Comment: Its really your choice.  I certainly think it would be an interesting post if presented a solution for a simple table-like type for the basic scenarios I've outlined.  That's if you have the time.  If not then its no big deal.

Comment: Added one example.  For each mixed-type need a class with a Property of the proper type.  See Int16 FieldValue.  For Date need DateTime FieldValue ...